# Does the $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty {\frac{{\sin (n)}}{{\sqrt {{n^3} + {{\cos }^3}(n)} }}} $ series converges?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\sin (n)}}{{\sqrt {{n^3} + {{\cos }^3}(n)} }}} $$
I tried to check with Maplesoft and Microsft Excel and seems this series is divergent.

Is my conjecture true? How can I prove it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you find a simpler series to compare with?

Comment: Try to show that this series is absolutely convergent by considering $|\sin n | < 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n \geq 2$ we have
$$
\frac{|\sin n|}{\sqrt{n^{3}+\cos^{3}(n)}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{3} + \cos^{3}(n)}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{3}-1}}.
$$
We have
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{3}-1}} \sim \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}
$$
as $n \to \infty$,
so the series $\sum_{n \geq 2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{3}-1}}$ converges by limit comparison test;
hence by comparison test we conclude that the series
$$
\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{\sin n}{\sqrt{n^{3}+\cos^{3}(n)}}
$$
converges absolutely,
and the convergence follows.

Comment: @JohnMa Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**
$$\left|\frac{\sin(n)}{\sqrt{n^3+\cos^3(n)}}\right|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3-1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\frac{\sin(n)}{\sqrt{n^3+\cos^3(n)}}\approx\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$. Then apply limit comparison test.

Comment: It's not quite true. That sine will have no limit.